# PYTHON - I need to remove some characters from rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to remove '-' from certain rows:
df:

```
description
- Fallo en el sensor del yaw
- Error enrollamiento máximo
Cannot couple without polo test
```

Expected output:

```
description
Fallo en el sensor del yaw
Error enrollamiento máximo
Cannot couple without polo test
```

Comment: `df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace('\\-+', '')` ?

Comment: Yep, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method to replace '-' with an empty string like this-

```
df["description"].replace({"- ": ""}, inplace = True, regex = True)
```

Note that you'll have to use '- ' instead of '-' because your data has '-' with trailing whitespace.

Comment: it removed all of the data, do I have to specify an axis?

Comment: `replace` the regex flag would need to be true for this to work. This code also raises an error (`NameError: name 'true' is not defined`). `True` in python has a capital `T`. `df["description"].replace({"- ": ""}, regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: Fixed the mistake.